# Java heap space error, delegating a stream in a jax-rs response

Tags: java, jax-rs, streaming, minio

In our system we are calling a backend that is the S3 server. And try to stream the file through the java service to the client. Problem is that for large files ( > 2 GiB ) we get a java heap error. The stream works for smaller files, but not for the largest there is. We are using the minio client to fetch data, and then stream it forward in the response.

```
    final InputStream is = s3client()
            .getObject(GetObjectArgs.builder().bucket(bucket)
                    .object(path).build());
    StreamingOutput fileStream = output -> {
        try {
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[8 * 1024];
            while ((nRead = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            is.close();
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("IOException while streaming data!", e);
        }
    };
    return Response
            .ok(fileStream, contentType)
            .build();
```

I don't see that the data should provide a heap space error as we (hopefully in my mind) are overwriting that allocation for all entries in the while loop. So I wonder if there is something in the hidden output or input streams that are increasing the heap space.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is coming from the S3 part and not from your output ??

Comment: @MrR: I am currently not sure of anything. The error occurs when I test the link in a general web window in chrome, which might mean that it is not using the output properly. I am just stumped atm. As I though the writing started once the receiving client called the write in the response.

Comment: what is `output` - if that's in memory you are writing a complete into memory ..if it's 2GiB filesize and your VM doesn't have enough heap allocated you will get a n out of heap error.

Answer (score 0):

So this was me brainfarting. I was not using the stream, but another function that tried to write to file before returning. And that makes sense that the heap dies horribly then.